# Send number from NumberPicker to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-number-picker

Is there a way to send Number from `NumberPicker` to `Firebase`? I have connected a `NumberPicker` library from `GITHUB`. But I want when select number to send to `Firebase`, is there a way ?

**I tried with this code :**

```
 String number = numberPicker.getText().toString().trim();
```

**Code for Firebase:**

```
private boolean updateProdus(String id, String number){

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("produse").child(id);

    Produse produse = new Produse(id, number);

    databaseReference.setValue(produse);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: where are you sending number to firebase ? post that code

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: this is the library https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean updateProdus(String id, String number){

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("produse").push();

databaseReference.child("number").setValue(number);
Toast.makeText(this, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return true;
}
```

Use `push()` to create a random id, then inside of it there will be a child that has the value number.

check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

you can get the number doing this:

```
String number=""+numberpicker.getValue();
```

Comment: yeah, but this code :  String number = numberPicker.getText().toString().trim(); is not work at all.  I can't send in this way "getText()" is red in my code.

Comment: @Clau congratulations!